# Node.JS TLS Sockets with SSL Authentication

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl

I am trying to achieve secure communication between hosts using Node.JS (version 14+) and TLS/SSL.

I need to be able to communicate not only with other hosts, but I want any given node to be able to communicate with itself as well. For example, I want one "main" node to control many "worker" nodes, and I want one more more "worker" nodes on the same machine as the "main" node.

The issue I am running into is `DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT` - which is presumably due to the same common name being used in the entire SSL generation process (my local IP address, for development). Here is how I am generating the SSL certificates: the only data input is the common name (as above); the rest is left as default. I found this script online somewhere.

```
# Private key for the root cert
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 2048

# root certificate
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 365 -out rootCA.crt

# Private key for the server cert
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048

# Signing request for the server 
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr

# Server cert using the root certificate
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 365 -sha256
```

Can someone please explain in detail how I can achieve what I want to do, or if I am even using SSL correctly? I want to use IP addresses in the certificate so they do not go on my DNS record.

I am new to SSL authentication, this is my first experience with it, and lots of the documentation online is either confusing or an advertisement for some security service.

My Node.JS client uses the following implementation:

Main:

```
let ca = await fsp.readFile(this.config.securityCALocation);
let cert = await fsp.readFile(this.config.securityCertLocation);
let key = await fsp.readFile(this.config.securityKeyLocation);
this.server = tls.createServer({
            rejectUnauthorized: true,
            requestCert: true,
            ca, cert, key
}, socket => this.incomingDataHandler(socket)).listen(this.config.port);
```

Worker:

```
let ca = await fsp.readFile(this.config.securityCALocation);
let cert = await fsp.readFile(this.config.securityCertLocation);
let key = await fsp.readFile(this.config.securityKeyLocation);
this.connection = tls.connect({
        host: this.config.mainHost,
        port: this.config.port,
        ca, cert, key
});
```

Comment: Your post is a  bit confusing since you mix up details about the certificate you want and the problems you have with this together with code which uses the certificate. But ultimately you don't provide the actual certificates you've created. The information I extract from your question is that you need to create a CA + leaf certificate where the leaf certificate can match an IP address. In this case the question I linked explains this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich In overview terms, I want to have secure communication between two Node.JS scripts over a network connection. I also want the two Node.JS scripts to be able to run on the same machine/ host.

Comment: The problem you have seems to come from the way you created the certificates. The linked question hopefully should help to master this problem. If there are new problems after that please ask a new question which describes the new errors you got. In other words: narrow down the solution one fixed problem at a time and don't expect somebody to cover all the problems you might have in a single post.